# iPad keeps asking for Apple ID login

Tags: ipad, apple-id, virus

My iPad 2 keeps asking for my Apple ID and iCloud login, cleared Safari hx, reset my iPad. I was contacted by Apple that my ID was reset by IE on a Windows PC. Changed my Apple ID from my iPhone. iPad keeps asking for Apple ID and iCloud login. I believe I have a virus on my iPad.
Suggestions?

Comment: How did apple contact you?  I'm highly suspicious of THAT.. Unless it was an email telling you to visit appleid.apple.com or iforgot.apple.com then I doubt the "contact" was really from apple.

Answer (score 1):

First reset your iPad: Settings > general > reset > Erase all content and settings.

Then go to icloud.com and click on reset password and reset your password to something complicated and not at all similar to the old password.

Now set up your iPad as a new device *not from a backup* (which may have the presumed virus) and sign into iCloud with your new password.

Keep an eye on it and watch for unusual activity on your icloud account.

Then take your time setting up your accounts and re-downloading your apps on the iPad.

Yeah I would do it that way rather than restoring from backup, it's a PITA but you'll have a clean iPad.

Comment: While I agree with this method, it its important to state that iOS & MacOS devices can not get viruses the way that they are made. They can only be affected by rogue programs that the user installs that they did not get from an App Store.

Answer (score 1):

Finally made it!

1. First, erase the problem app
2. Go to settings, iTunes store, and sign out
3. **Without signing back in**, open the App Store.
4. Locate the app and download it
5. It will ask you for an Apple ID. Input the one you want.
6. It will download everything from the Apple ID from bullet #5!